# Programmatic ways to join AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory

How to join a system into AzureAD programatically? Can anyone recommend commands or powershell option through which we can join AzureAD

Answer (score 1):

At present there are no PowerShell scripts for joining devices to Azure AD.

You can upvote the feature request here and subscribe to keep track of updates from the product [team](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20399941-all-powershell-bash-script-azure-ad-join).

There are lot of ways you can bring your devices to azure ad join directly like users can go through the Azure AD join process either during Windows Out of Box Experience (OOBE)

Similarly bulk enrollment and Autopilot) which provide a richer experience to join devices to Azure AD

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_1H2k8ZnwmdPj89L&Q_CHL=gl
>